# How many different four letter words can you from with the letters from the sentence "There is no game"?

Tags: combinatorics

At [exactly this point in this video](https://youtu.be/HSCg1GcZFns?t=253), the "game" prompts the player to fill four slots with the letters of a sign that they have just destroyed. The sign in question used to say "There is no game". Depending on what word you form, the game might spawn an item or reveal a new area.

I am curious as to how many different words you can form with the given thirteen letters.

I believe I have the correct answer but since this isn't a textbook question, there's no way to verify it without having another person solve it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Have you count the number of occurence of each letter in the sentence?

Comment: @user Yes, I did.

Comment: And what was the result?

Comment: E occurs thrice. All other letters occur just once.

Comment: So split all words in 4 types according to the number of E's and count.

Comment: Is the answer 13 * 12 * 11 * 10?

Comment: It would be so if all letters occur only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting the words in 4 classes according to the count of "e" in a word one obtains the following number of possible words:
$$
\binom {10}4 \frac {4!}{0!}+\binom {10}3 \frac {4!}{1!}+\binom {10}2\frac {4!}{2!}+\binom {10}1\frac {4!}{3!}.
$$

Comment: So you did "10 choose 4" * 4! to get the number of words with zero "e"'s in them. Do I have that right?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "9 choose 4" * 4! because you're excluding "e"?

Comment: How do you get this formula?

Comment: @temporary Why have you changed my answer? Care to explain?

Comment: @temporary Whatever you think of the answer, please refrain from editing it. You still have the possibility to write your own answer. Actually, for this specific question, I am not convinced by either version.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin The four terms correspond to $k= 0,1,2,3$ of "e", respectively. The collection is supplemented by $4-k$ (of 10) other letters. Finally the 4 letters are permuted taking care that $k $ letters are indistinguishable.

Comment: How you count short words like "r", "th", "ht"? For instance,with the letters $a, b, c$, you could get $16$ words: $1$ (the empty word), $a$, $b$, $c$, $ab$, $ba$, $ac$, $ca$, $bc$, $cb$, $abc$, $acb$, $bac$, $bca$, $cab$, $cba$.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin The question suggests that a word consists of *exactly* 4 letters.

Comment: @user My bad, I should have looked at the video...